# iOS 実機だと `UIImage imageNamed` が nil を返しイメージを読み込まない

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, xcassets

```
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(screen.size.width/2, screen.size.height/2, 128, 128);
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    [self addSubview:imageView];

    imageView.animationImages = @[
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower01.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower02.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower03.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower04.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower05.png"],
```

上記のコードをシミュレーターで実行するとエラーも無く実行できるのですが、実機で実行すると `animationImages`に画像を入れる過程で以下のエラーが表示されます。

`attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]`

なので`nil`を加えようと以下のように変更してみたのですが、今度は`unrecognized selector sent to instance`というエラーが返ってきました。

```
NSArray *animationImages = @[[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil,
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower01.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower02.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower03.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower04.png"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower05.png"], nil
                                ]];
```

パラパラのアニメーションを行うために画像を格納していきたいのですが、どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: 念の為確認ですが、実機にも fire_flower01.png などをコピーしていますよね？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。すみません、iOS開発についてまだわからないことが多く、実機への画像のコピーを初めて聞きました。。。実機へコピーするにはプロジェクトのフォルダに直接画像をコピペするのでしょうか？

Comment: もともとプロジェクト内に置かれている画像でしたら問題はないかと思います。なお、「attempt to insert nil object 〜」というメッセージは、[UIImage imageNamed:@"fire_flower01.png"] の結果が nil であるということかと思います(おそらく fire_flower01.png が見つからないのではないかと)。

Comment: 昔、@2x(もしくは@3x)イメージが足りないとかで同様のことになったことがあります。自動選択させるためにイメージはカタログ(xcassets)に追加してください。（現在使用しているのが非Retina端末エミュレーターであれば、Retinaディスプレイを持ったiOS機のエミュレータで試してみてください。同じ現象になるならそれです。）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。xcassetsに画像を追加したところ、エラーもなくアニメーションを実行することができました！誠にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

コメントで解決しましたが、 プロジェクト内のカタログにイメージファイルをを追加していなかったということでした。

ここに補足含めてまとめておきます。

イメージ取得の API では、リソースが見つからないと `nil`　を返すものがあります。　イメージリソースが見つからない原因には、以下のどちらかが有力です。

1. 単純に、イメージファイルがプロジェクトに追加されていないもしくは、ファイル名が不正
2. 実行時に、`@2x`, `@3x` 等のバージョンのリソースが読み込まれようとしたが失敗

今回は後者でしょう。環境によって、本来どのタイプのリソースが必要になるかは、　[iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) で大まかに知ることができます。

- `@1x` : iPhone 3GS　まで
- `@2x` : iPhone 4,4s,5,5s,6 等の Retina 機
- `@3x` : 現状 iPhone 6 Plus のみ
- iPad であれば、さらに、 `~ipad`　がバージョンに付加される

といったところ。実際は、カタログ (.xcassets)にリソースを追加する、 または、 ベクタイメージを用意することでことで、 これらの選択を意識しなくても良くなっています。今回は、 Retina 環境の実機が `@2x` バージョンのファイルを読みに行き、 `nil` を返したと推測されます。 Mac 上で使用していたエミュレータが Retina ディスプレイのものではなかったため、ローカルテスト中にはエラーが出なかったのでしょう。

参考: [SO: Xcode 6 - xcassets for universal image support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020979/xcode-6-xcassets-for-universal-image-support)

Comment: 環境によって異なるタイプのリソースが必要になるのですね。勉強になります。詳しい解説までしてくださり、誠にありがとうございます。リンク先もこれから参考にさせていただきます。